# How to handle questions that are not useful for future readers?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes there are questions which are just very unlikely to ever be useful to anybody else. This can occur if the problem is specific to the authors code and the answer is trivial. Often these questions are also poor in other ways, but not necessarily.

How do you handle such questions?

My first approach was to deliver the answer to close it and get it out of the way for more important questions. E.g consider this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44220244/why-i-am-getting-matrix-dimension-error-in-the-line-while-calculating-n) where the problem is just a small typo. And while i'm sure there will be many more beginners in Matlab who mix up `./` and `/` i'm equally sure that that problem has occurred on this site already a thousand times and future Matlab beginners are unlikely to ever find it.

However, an alternate way is to answer the question in a comment and then encourage the author to delete his own question before anybody answers it. E.g. take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44227901/calling-function-with-2-parameters-on-matrix-of-dimension-n-x-2?noredirect=1), which was answered in a the comments and then encouraged to be deleted. This is also a good example of an actually very well posed question even tough it's unlikely to be useful to anybody else.

By now I think the second way is a lot better because the authors problem is solved and stackoverflow does not get filled with useless questions, which is a win/win. Or are there any better solutions? Answering the question but at the same time downvoting it to make it disappear would also work but that would discourage (new) users to ask questions.

Comment: _"the authors problem is solved"_ - we really don't care. This isn't a "help me" forum, it's supposed to be a collection of unique, high-quality questions and answers. If it's a simple typo, vote to close as such. If it's a duplicate that _they_ couldn't find, _you_ go find it and use it as a duplicate close vote target.

Comment: *"And while i'm sure there will be many more beginners in Matlab who mix up ./ and / i'm equally sure that that problem has occurred on this site already a thousand times and future Matlab beginners are unlikely to ever find it."* - Then spent a few minutes and find a possible dupe which covers that issues and explains the differences. If there isn't any, then write such a Q&A yourself (with a good title so others can find it) and then flag similar questions as a duplicate of your new question.

Comment: I don't agree that it's a `win/win` with the second suggestion. It would be great if all the questions were to be asked in a fashion that will help other users in future, but it's not a strict rule that we enforce on SO, because it will automatically make thousands of questions off-topic, and it would be almost impossible to ask new questions for a lot of users

Comment: @AlonEitan So should I if possible heavily edit the question to make it useful?

Comment: Answering is also better then providing a solution in the comments because it allow to set a `itemprop="acceptedAnswer"` attribute on the accepted answer and then Google ["knows"](http://schema.org/acceptedAnswer) that that specific question was actually answered

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger This is a bit tricky, you can't edit it to such extent where it conflicts with author's intent. We have a rejecting option for that. So every case should be considered separately and there is no absolute recommendation I can suggest about editing

Comment: CodeCaster and Tom: Thx, that makes sense

Comment: @AlonEitan I see, then referring to a similar question makes more sense depending on the situation

Comment: @LeanderMoesinger Yup. Flagging as duplicate is almost always a good bet, assuming you flag to the a real duplicate. A lot of times I see cases where the OP don't understand how the duplicate question is related - Which leave them 2 options: Try to learn and understand why, or edit and explain why that duplicate is wrong (And then the community decide if to reopen the question for answering)

Comment: @TinyGiant So meta! I guess i didn't see that thread because i didn't even think mine could be related with duplicates, so I never searched for that term. But yes, it sort of is one - and together with the comments here I think I know how to handle things now. Thx all!